# Difference between C++ openssl/aes and Go crypto/aes

Tags: c++, go, openssl, aes

I have two programs on C++ and Go for encrypt data using AES, but they returns different results. Could you explain me the difference? How I can write similar code to get the same result using Go?

**C++**

> g++ aes.cpp -o aes -O3 -lcrypto -std=c++11 && ./aes

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <openssl/aes.h>

using std::cout;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    uint8_t result[16] = {0};
    uint8_t key[32] = {
      52, 51, 51, 100, 52, 53, 98, 57, 51, 98, 98, 98, 102, 102, 56, 100,
      54, 53, 53, 49, 55, 56, 54, 51, 50, 102, 49, 56, 101, 97, 101, 97,
    };
    uint8_t data[16] = {
      89, 0, 192, 238, 251, 3, 19, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 236,
    };

    AES_KEY ctx;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(&key[0], 128, &ctx);

    AES_encrypt(data, result, &ctx);

    std::cout << "Result: ";

    for (auto const& value: result) {
        std::cout << unsigned(value) << ",";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

> Result: 65,68,199,89,141,129,6,202,211,198,47,54,212,0,243,130

**Go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    result := make([]byte, 16)
    key := []byte{
        52, 51, 51, 100, 52, 53, 98, 57, 51, 98, 98, 98, 102, 102, 56, 100,
        54, 53, 53, 49, 55, 56, 54, 51, 50, 102, 49, 56, 101, 97, 101, 97,
    }
    data := []byte{89, 0, 192, 238, 251, 3, 19, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 236}

    cipher, err := aes.NewCipher(key)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cipher.Encrypt(result, data)

    log.Println(result)
}
```

> Result: 18 144 147 200 175 53 202 191 80 17 142 126 228 220 57 180

Comment: Your C++ version uses only 128 bits of the key, whereas your Go version uses all 256 bits of the key. Thus, the difference is in AES-128 vs. AES-256.  Do you get the same results when calling `AES_set_encrypt_key(&key[0], 256, &ctx);`? Or to answer the question, try to use in Go `key := []byte{52, 51, 51, 100, 52, 53, 98, 57, 51, 98, 98, 98, 102, 102, 56, 100}`

Comment: @zett42, you are helped me. Thank you for explaination.